# MediaPlayer doesnt work after upgrade to Gingerbread 2.3.4

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I have an app that will play a tone, it did work perfectly until I installed it on Gingerbread 2.3.4 based android phone. The problem is I don't see any exception thrown, and no sound is generated, exactly same code does play sound in pre gingerbread phone. Here is the code that plays the sound.

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    //mp.release();
    try {
        String audioFilePath = "content://media/internal/audio/media/20";  
        mp.setDataSource(audioFilePath);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have comments placed before and after the code to play sound, all comments are printed as if sound is played, but there is no sound.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

never mind, seems like somehow the volume on alerts was set to 0, I actually went to actual folder, selected a file, played it manually and then turned the volume up while being played and all was well afterwards.